# jQuery noob: transfer not transferring

Tags: jquery, html

[I made an example](http://jsfiddle.net/TuMsc/), I copied it straight from the [jQuery website](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer#option-className) yet, it doesn't transfer..

HTML:

```
   <div class="addToCart">
     BLAHHHH
     </div>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <br>
     <div class="handelv">
     MORE BLAAAHH
     </div>​
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(".addToCart").click(function () {
      var i = 1 - $(".addToCart").index(this);
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".handelv").eq(i) }, 1000);
});

  });​
```

What have I gotten wrong?

Comment: have you tried just `$(".addToCart").index();` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TuMsc/7/

1. You weren't including the UI library in the example
2. `$(".handelv").eq(i)` where `i = 1`. Your selector only matches one element; so you need to set `i` to `0`.
3. You need to define a style for `.ui-effects-transfer`, so that a visible-something happens.

All your code can be changed to just:

```
$(".addToCart").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".handelv") }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I needed to include he UI library and the CSS also. Great help, I am new to jQuery so thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is misunderstanding how the selectors in the example are being used. The `index` and `eq` methods are selecting either the first or second div.

if you change the code to this:

```
$(".addToCart").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".handelv") }, 1000);
});
```

​
You also need to set `.ui-effects-transfer` to display something; a border is used in the example (which is the class of the element that is displayed during the transfer) and include jquery UI

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".addToCart").click(function () {     
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".handelv") }, 1000);
});

  });​
```